# Solr search used method queryForFacetPage only 10 records return

Tags: solr

```java
public FacetPage<SolrArticleDocument> facetSearch(String searchTerm, Pageable page) {
    SimpleFacetQuery facetQuery = new SimpleFacetQuery(new SimpleStringCriteria(searchTerm));
    Sort sort = new Sort(Direction.DESC,"trendingCount");
    facetQuery.addSort(sort);
    FacetOptions options = new FacetOptions();
    options.addFacetOnFlieldnames(getFacetFields());
    facetQuery.setFacetOptions(options);
    facetQuery.setPageRequest(page);
    return cmsTemplate.queryForFacetPage(facetQuery, SolrArticleDocument.class);
}
```

used above method and only return 10 records but expected out is return all records..

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using the Spring Data Solr-framework from your method names. Here you can [set the facet.limit option through `setFacetLimit`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/solr/core/query/FacetOptions.html#setFacetLimit-int-), which defaults to 10. This sets the number of terms returned for each facet. You can set the value to a negative value to return all terms, but if you need a certain amount of terms - use a specific value instead so Lucene can shortcut the facet building if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```java
facetQuery.setRows(999); // or any other big number =/
```

Not as good as you would expect, but it does the trick.